# ssh executes remote command in the background

Tags: linux, ssh

I know I can execute a command on a remote machine using "`ssh ip_addr "command"`", and this will return after 'command' exits. How can I execute a command in the background on the remote machine so that I don't need to wait for the 'command' to exits? I tried `ssh ipaddr "command &"` but it didn't seems to work. An alternative is `ssh ipaddr "command" &` which put the ssh command in the background but it doesn't look clean. Suggestions?

Comment: What's the purpose of this?

Comment: It does work to me. How do you check that it is not workign?